# Chrome background tab high CPU usage: how to profile?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome tab that uses 100% CPU when it's restored from a chrome crash. When I bring it to the foreground it drops back to normal CPU.

How can I start profiling on the tab without switching to it, so I can catch it in the act of misbehaving?